Error: The database returned the following error: could not load file or assembly system.data.common version=8.0.0.0
On Windows 10 PC
Installed
VS2022 and tried to create a base WPF application with c#.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient - 5.2.1
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core - 23.4.0
.Net 8.0
Created a new DataSet, connected to an Oracle Database 12, tested connection successfully.
Tried to create a TableAdapter, after few steps, when click Finish, I get this error:
Generated SELECT statement.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Common, Version=8.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Was expecting a table adapter to be created.
enter image description here

Do you have any other library installed?

When I look at "Packages" folder in the Solution, I see "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (5.2.1) , Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration(8.0.0) and "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (23.4.0). Then in Frameworks folder, I see "Microsoft.NETCore.App", "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref" and "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF"

Please additional your code

No code, just the skeleton of the wpf app. I don't know how to add an image of my solution explorer.

Just added an image to the original question.

How do you create the table adapter? Complete your code.

I tried to create the table adapter, not through code, but right mouse click on the DataSet Designer, that appears when I add to the project a "new item/DataSet", and then went through the set of dialogs until I reached the "Finish", where I got the error above.

Try to install package "System.Data.Common"

I couldn't find "system.data.common version=8.0.0.0", not sure what to install to have that available in VS2022.

Maybe you can find something can help you here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211526/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-error-when-deploying-application-on
